# RTK Query Simple Explanation through Code

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-redux, react-hook-form, rtk-query

Please someone simply explain the RTK query in react.
Is it replacing axios?
For e.g: If there is a react form having the following details
FirstName, LastName, City, CustID and Submit button.
when user inserts data there and click on submit, then this will be store in database through spring boot.
Then user can fetch the data by CustID in the UI.

How this above process happens, and what RTK query basically doing here.
TIA

I have gone through rtk docs but getting confuse, so need a simple explanation, or any code will be better

Answer (score 1):

RTK Query makes requests for you and it uses the technology that you put in as `baseQuery`. Usually, that is `fetchBaseQuery`, which is based on `fetch` - a browser API that ships with browsers for years at this point and that can do everything that axios can do, without having to add 8kb for axios to your bundle.

Apart from that detail question, I would highly recommend that you don't go through the docs, but through the [Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics) to understand how to use it.